# Use sed to replace part of a string leaving other part represented by regex unchanged

Tags: vim, regex, sed, text-editing, vi

Consider you want to replace part of a sentence and leave other part represented by the regular expression (regex) *unchanged*.  For instance, here's a text file

text1.txt

```
A Egg
b Egg
C Egg
D Egg
E Pig
```

You want to change this to

```
A Chick
b Egg
C Chick
D Chick
E Pig
```

In this case, `Egg` in every line with any upper case, space and `Egg` has changed into `Chick`. In the regular expression, the target pattern can be represented by `[A-Z] Egg`.

How can you replace these by `☆ Chick` where ☆ is the original upper case character?  The command below doesn't/shouldn't work but hope it helps you understand what I want...

```
sed -i "s/[A-Z] Egg/[A-Z] Chick/g" ./text*.txt   # incorrect
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a capture group that retains the first uppercase letter:

```
sed  "s/\([A-Z]\) Egg/\1 Chick/" file.txt
A Chick
b Egg
C Chick
D Chick
E Pig
```

Where:

- `\([A-Z]\)` is the capture group 1 that contains the first uppercase letter
- `\1` is a backreference to the group 1 (i.e. the content of group 1)

*I've remove the `-i` option to show the result, use it if you want to replace inplace.*

---

If you want to replace inplace in all files `text*.txt`:

```
sed -i  "s/\([A-Z]\) Egg/\1 Chick/" text*.txt
```

Comment: @Culip: see my edit.

Comment: (Please ignore my comment earlier.  After fixing a typo in my test script it worked.)